# How do I get Gmail to open new windows in full-screen by default?

Tags: gmail, full-screen

Is there anyway to open the 'in new window' by default to full-screen? Whenever we click this, we have to manually maximize the window.

[image: buttons with 'open in new window' highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

Hold down either the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click *Compose* to compose a new Gmail message in a new web browser tab. The new Compose screen is full height and ~90% full width in my web browser. The part of the new tab that has the compose workspace in it has a 5% margin on both sides, right and left, however the new compose tab is full screen. These two margins might be a feature to make Gmail easier to use for people who are used to working with other email clients that have an additional navigation pane on the left side and the new message pane does not extend to 100% of the width of the screen.

I thought the 90% width of the Compose workspace might have something to do with *Keyboard shortcuts* in Gmail Settings, but it works the same way with *Keyboard shortcuts off* and *Keyboard shortcuts on*.